# How to mock a constant value

Tags: python, pytest, python-mock, pytest-mock

I have a structure like so:

```
mod1
├── mod2
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils.py
└── tests
    └── test_utils.py
```

where

- `__init__.py`:

```
CONST = -1
```

- `utils.py`:

```
from mod1.mod2 import CONST

def mod_function():
    print(CONST)
```

- `test_utils.py`:

```
from mod1.mod2.utils import mod_function

def test_mod_function(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch("mod1.mod2.CONST")
    mock.return_value = 1000
    mod_function()
```

I'm using [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/) with [`mocker`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

By running `python -m pytest -s ./mod1/tests` I expected to see `1000` as an output, but got `-1`. Why?

How to patch a constant from the `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Patching affects *names*, not values. You use a global variable `mod_function` that gets *initialized* using the original value of `mod1.mod2.utils.mod_function` in `test_mod_function`, and the global is unaffected by the patch.

Comment: When I was creating MRE I forgot to paste in the `CONST`, sorry for the confusion! Fixed now.

Comment: I will quad check before posting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `patch("mod1.mod2.CONST")` does is really to set the `CONST` attribute of the module object `mod1.mod2` to a different object. It does not affect any existing names referencing the original `mod1.mod2.CONST` object.

When `utils.py` does:

```
from mod1.mod2 import CONST
```

it creates a name `CONST` in the namespace of the `mod1.mod2.utils` module, referencing the object `-1` currently referenced by the `mod1.mod2.CONST` name.

And when `test_mod_function` then does:

```
mock = mocker.patch("mod1.mod2.CONST")
```

it modifies `mod1.mod2` such that its `CONST` attribute now references a `Mock` object, while the `CONST` name in `mod1.mod2.utils` continues to reference the object `-1`, which is why setting `mock.return_value` does not affect the outcome of `mod_function`.

To properly test `mod_function` with a mock `CONST` you can either patch `CONST` in the namespace where `mod_function` is defined:

```
mock = mocker.patch("mod1.mod2.utils.CONST")
```

or you can defer the import of `mod1.mod2.utils` until `mod1.mod2.CONST` has been patched:

```
def test_mod_function(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch("mod1.mod2.CONST")
    mock.return_value = 1000
    from mod1.mod2.utils import mod_function
    mod_function()
```